# Python M2crypto error

Tags: python, m2crypto

I am trying to build `crda` agent module on a cross platform(ARM).
To build the same, one of the input module is `m2crypto` shared object file.
I have successfully cross compiled and `m2crypto.so` file has been generated.

when I give the `make` command, python script is called internally which should 
take `m2crypto.so` module as input and should generate openssl(RSA) keys.

The problem I am facing is the python script couldn't import any of the modules from the `__m2crypto.so` file.
I am using python 2.4 version.
And the error i am getting is

```
$ make

GEN keys-ssl.c
Trusted pubkeys: /home/tools/crda/pubkeys/linville.key.pub.pem
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./utils/key2pub.py", line 6, in ?
import m2crypto
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/m2crypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [keys-ssl.c] Error 1
```

where as, when I compile `m2crypto` for host machine(x86 platform) and try to build the `crda` for the same, 
python is able to import the `m2crypto.so` file.

Any suggestions on how to build it successfully on the different platform(ARM).

Thanks in Advance,
Rams ch

Comment: Are you sure that `/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload/m2crypto.so` is readable by current user?

Answer (score 0):

This question has some age ;-) 
I was faced to the same question in the last few days. Maybe the solution which fixed my problem is also helpfull for anyone reading this question. I was using a patch from openwrt:

[101-make_crypto_use_optional.patch](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/package/crda/patches/101-make_crypto_use_optional.patch?rev=21956)

This patch removes the crypto setup from crda. For me this is was okay...